# How to create pivot table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Currently my T-SQL statement,

```
SELECT 
    ep.AgentOwnerName, ep.AgencyName, ep.LocationName, ep.AgentNo, 
    ep.TY, ROUND(ROUND(CAST(ep.EP as money), -1), 0) as EP, 
    ROUND(ROUND(CAST(il.[Incurred Loss] as float), -1), 0) as [Incurred Loss], 
    CONCAT(CAST((ROUND(ROUND(CAST(il.[Incurred Loss] as float), -1), 0) / ROUND(ROUND(CAST(ep.EP as float), -1), 0) + 0.085) * 100.0 as decimal(10, 0)), '%') as [Loss Ratio with LAE]
FROM 
    #tempEarnedPremiumByTreatyYearAgentOwner ep
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    #tempIncurredLossByTreatyYearAgentOwner il ON ep.AgencySysID = il.AgencySysID
                                               AND ep.LocationSysID = il.LocationSysID
                                               AND ep.TY = il.TY
WHERE 
    (ep.EP > 0 AND il.[Incurred Loss] > 0)
    AND ep.TY IN ('16-17', '17-18', '18-19', '19-20', '20-21')
ORDER BY 
    ep.AgentOwnerName ASC, ep.AgencyName ASC, ep.LocationName ASC, 
    ep.AgentNo ASC, ep.TY ASC;
```

Creates this output:

[image]

And I'm needing the results to be displayed in this format:

[image]

Any suggestions/direction would be greatly appreciated. I've tried doing this in SSRS but adding multiple column groups seems fairly difficult in SSRS. Thanks.

Comment: My suggestion is to read documentation on `PIVOT`.  Ideally, the pivoting should be done in SSRS.

Comment: Eric, I would agree.  However, I cannot seem to add 3 separate and distinct COLUMN GROUPS in SSRS.  I know I must be doing something wrong I just can't get the column grouping right. I've read numerous posts about the PIVOT in SQL and unfortunately it's not very easy.  I'll keep trying.  Thanks.

Comment: How does your output look like now?

Answer (score 0):

Answer updated.

Wrap your query in a CTE, then use `sum(case when...)`:

```
with cte as (
    SELECT 
        ep.AgentOwnerName, ep.AgencyName, ep.LocationName, ep.AgentNo, 
        ep.TY, ROUND(ROUND(CAST(ep.EP as money), -1), 0) as EP, 
        ROUND(ROUND(CAST(il.[Incurred Loss] as float), -1), 0) as [Incurred Loss], 
        CONCAT(CAST((ROUND(ROUND(CAST(il.[Incurred Loss] as float), -1), 0) / ROUND(ROUND(CAST(ep.EP as float), -1), 0) + 0.085) * 100.0 as decimal(10, 0)), '%') as [Loss Ratio with LAE]
    FROM #tempEarnedPremiumByTreatyYearAgentOwner ep
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #tempIncurredLossByTreatyYearAgentOwner il 
        ON ep.AgencySysID = il.AgencySysID
        AND ep.LocationSysID = il.LocationSysID
        AND ep.TY = il.TY
    WHERE (ep.EP > 0 AND il.[Incurred Loss] > 0)
            AND ep.TY IN ('16-17', '17-18', '18-19', '19-20', '20-21')
    )
select AgentOwnerName, 
    AgencyName, 
    LocationName,
    AgentNo, 
    sum(case when TY = [16-17] then [EP] else 0 end) as [Earned Premium 16-18],
    ...,
    sum(case when TY = [16-17] then [Incurred Loss] else 0 end) as [Incurred Loss 16-17],
    sum(case when TY = [17-18] then [Incurred Loss] else 0 end) as [Incurred Loss 17-18],
    ...,
from cte
group by AgentOwnerName,
    AgencyName,
    LocationName,
    AgentNo;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @dkritz, however, that does not seem to work for me.

Comment: Hi @Melinda, I've updated my answer to include your original query in a CTE, then use `sum(case...)`. Let me know if that works.